# JS DateTimePicker onChange event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

JS datetimepicker **`onChange`** event not working at all.

I've tried **`OnSelect`**, **`OnClose`**, **`OnChange`**, **`OnHide`**, **`OnChangeMonth`**
to trigger **`datetimepicker`** event, but none of them works.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" id="Datetimepicker" data-toggle="datetimepicker" data-target="#Datetimepicker" autocomplete="off" style="width: 200px;" />
```

```
$("#Datetimepicker").datetimepicker({
    format: 'MMM,YYYY',
    defaultDate: today,
    onSelect: function () {
        alert("It works!");
    }
})

$("#Datetimepicker").datetimepicker("change",function(){
    alert("It works!")});


$("#Datetimepicker").datetimepicker("changeDate",function(){
    alert("It works!")});
```

I've tried many ways, but still none of them working. Do I need to provide some other js library in order to make it work? Appreciate your help.

Comment: Are you using this [datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)?

Comment: Hi, I'm actually using bootstrap-4 datetimepicker

Comment: Can you share the link please?

Comment: Sure!
https://tempusdominus.github.io/bootstrap-4/Usage/

Comment: I'll work on it. Please add your HTML code as well to your question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As mentioned by @Bluety you have to use the [events](https://tempusdominus.github.io/bootstrap-4/Events/) provided by the library.

In your case you can use `change.datetimepicker` event. The event handler function receives old date and new date which can be used for any comparisons you might need.

```
$("#Datetimepicker").on("change.datetimepicker", ({date, oldDate}) => {              
                 //Use date and oldDate here
          })
```

Also note that, in your case the input element is same as datepicker target, This can lead to duplicate events triggered .................................................................................................

```
id="Datetimepicker" data-toggle="datetimepicker" data-target="#Datetimepicker"
```

You can run the snippet below and change the date to see multiple alerts for one event.

```js
$("#Datetimepicker").datetimepicker({
          format: 'MMM,YYYY',
          defaultDate: new Date()
      }
      );

      $("#Datetimepicker").on("change.datetimepicker", ({date, oldDate}) => {
              console.log("New date", date);
              console.log("Old date", oldDate);
              alert("Changed date")
      })
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.0.1/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.0.1/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css" />





<div id="target" style="position:relative" data-target-input="nearest">
        <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" id="Datetimepicker" data-toggle="datetimepicker" data-target="#Datetimepicker" autocomplete="off" style="width: 200px;" />
    </div>
```

To avoid this, you can use the parent as `data-target`. This is how the examples look in the documentation as well

```
<div id="target" style="position:relative" data-target-input="nearest">
  <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" id="Datetimepicker" data-toggle="datetimepicker" data-target="#target" autocomplete="off" style="width: 200px;" />
</div>
```

Run the snippet below and change dates to see single alert.

```js
$("#target").datetimepicker({
  format: 'MMM,YYYY',
  defaultDate: new Date()
});

$("#target").on("change.datetimepicker", ({
  date,
  oldDate
}) => {
  console.log("New date", date);
  console.log("Old date", oldDate);
  alert("Changed date")

})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.0.1/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.0.1/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css" />

<div id="target" style="position:relative" data-target-input="nearest">
  <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" id="Datetimepicker" data-toggle="datetimepicker" data-target="#target" autocomplete="off" style="width: 200px;" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

When I look at the documentation I see that events have been defined by the library.

You can use the "on" function of jQuery with a custom event "change.datetimepicker" defined by the library and indicated in the documentation (https://tempusdominus.github.io/bootstrap-4/Events/).

```
$("#Datetimepicker").on("change.datetimepicker",function(){
    alert("It works!")});
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, it works, but it trigger the event twice when a date is selected:
"It works"
"It works"

Comment: Tried "update.datetimepicker", it's not working btw

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#Datetimepicker").datetimepicker().on('changeDate', function(e) {
  console.log('hey');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For the users that have the newer version of this lib (tempus dominus) you can do something like this:

```
$('#yourElement').on(tempusDominus.Namespace.events.change, (e) => {
     console.log(e,'do stuff..');
});
```